# Foreground Service Stopped after several hours

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, service, location

Created Android service to update location in background and integrate it with Unity. Service works fine at start but after several hours service stops and it doesn't update user location.

Below is code snippet of **OnStartCommand, OnCreate**, Override method.

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{


    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    return START_STICKY;
}

public void onCreate()
{

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        NotificationChannel   channel  = new NotificationChannel(
                "channel_01",
                "My Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        );
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "channel_01");
        startForeground(12345678, builder.build());


    }
    initializeLocationManager();

    stopForeground(true);


}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service must remain as Foreground if you need to run "forever". The problem is that you are stopping your foreground.

Try this:

```
import android.app.Notification;
...
public void onCreate()
{
   super.onCreate();
   ...

   // Build the notification.
   Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();

   // And Start Foreground.
   startForeground(SERVICE_ID, notification); // Where SERVICE_ID is any integer.
}
```

And:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
        //Return START_STICKY to inform the system that service must be woken up automatically if destroyed
        return START_STICKY;
}
```

**NOTE:** You can refer to this sample. https://github.com/android/location-samples/tree/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService

**EDIT:**

If you really need to mantain this in the Background (and not Foreground), you can refer to Workers. More info here: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/workmanager-periodicity-ff35185ff006
Keep in mind that location in background could be less frequent (1 update each 15 min). But in foreground you can make it more frequent.

Comment: Thanks peter for detailed answer.  
is it possible to run service as foreground without showing notification bar when app goes into background ?

Comment: @AsadAli Im sorry but "Foreground services must display a Notification" as said in https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services. If the service is in the Foreground then the notification is mandatory, but if it goes to background (not foreground) then the notification is not mandatory.

Comment: Hi there, do you know if it's possible to know if Android kills the service?